# How to close keyboard automatically after when the user finishes editing in Goodie Bag PinviewEditText.?

Tags: android

Keyboard does not close even after starts new activity.

I want When the user has finished editing, start a new activity without pressing done/enter.

```
pinview.setPinViewEventListener(new Pinview.PinViewEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataEntered(Pinview pinview, boolean fromUser) {
            String pin=pinview.getValue();
            callApi(pin);

        }
    });
```

and xml is

```
   <com.goodiebag.pinview.Pinview
            android:id="@+id/pinview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:pinWidth="30dp"
            app:pinHeight="30dp"
            app:pinLength="6"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:cursorVisible="false"
            app:forceKeyboard="true"
            app:hint=""
            app:inputType="number"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:password="false"/>
```

Comment: have u tried `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Comment: Yes I have tried this, but It is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set by code as follow,

## Kotlin

```
val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)
```

## Android java

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

or in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these....

In you menifest file add these two line in activity where you are using PinView.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/hello_activity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" />
```

Then in you code where you are calling the callApi method add the following lines..

```
pinview.setPinViewEventListener(new Pinview.PinViewEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataEntered(Pinview pinview, boolean fromUser) {
        String pin = pinview.getValue();

        // Add this following code.. it works
        if (pin.length() == 6) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
otpPinView.onKey(otpPinView.getFocusedChild(), KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
```

and you can use this also :

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = 
    (InputMethodManager) context.
        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
    this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```